# iOS apps in the kids category and apps intended for kids cannot include third-party advertising will Apple allow after 3rd sept?

Tags: ios, app-store

As per new AppStore review Guidelines 1.3 and 5.1.4 for iOS Apps Apple updated guideline "apps in the kids category and apps intended for kids cannot include third-party advertising or analytics software and may not transmit data to third parties(https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=06032019j)".
My App is in the kids category and we are using superawesomeads ("https://www.superawesome.com/awesomeads").

**So my question is:** So, should i remove superawesomeads as per Apple's new guideline?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The answer is obviously no. It is a 3rd party service.

Comment: @Paulw11 in my iOS App i am showing superawesomeads in my App which is in kids category. So, should i remove superawesomeads as per Apple's new guideline?

Comment: Yes. You can't have ads in a kids category app, so you can either remove the ads or take the app out of the kids category of the App Store.

Comment: @kathiriahemendu please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Apple Review Guidelines for the new Applications it will be immediately in effect.

**So here are the rules :**

1. If you are uploading brand new application you must not use third party ads or analytics on it. Other wise Apple will reject your Application.
2. If you are updating your existing application, than Apple has allowed the time till 3rd September 2019 to remove the third party ads & analytics. After that if you send for update, It can get rejected.

Hope this will help everyone.

Comment: @Paulw11 sorry, didn't get your point

Comment: and exist app not update to comply, delete analytics code or ads id to stop ads also will be violate?

Comment: @DzungPV there is nothing defined how they will track for the existing Apps. So it will not effect for the existing apps. But somehow at any stage you would needed to update the existing apps.

Comment: Then how some kids apps on Appstore still showing ads? like talking tom app.

Comment: Could I instead create a new app, under the same name? It would not anymore be made for kids. And then also deactivate the old app? Instead of updating it? Does anyone have some insight here?